# Symmetric solution of ODE

Tags: differential-equations, constraint

Is it possible to force DSolve to calculate the symmetric solution?

Obviously the ode `x''[t] + x[t] == 0` has the symmetric solution `Cos[t]`

```
{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[-t] == x[t]} /. x -> (  Cos[#] & )
(*True,True *)
```

but MMA can't find it

```
DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[-t] == x[t]}, x, t]
(*DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[-t] == x[t]}, x, t]*)
```

Any suggestions how to solve such problems? Thanks!

Comment: Why not solve the equation normally, and then take the even part `(x[t] + x[-t])/2`?

Comment: @ J.M.iscomputer-less Thanks , it's as simple as that!

Comment: Note that the above only works for linear ODEs.

Answer (score 1):

```
In[1]:= DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, t]


Out[1]= {{x -> Function[{t}, C[1] Cos[t]]}}
```

Comment: Thanks. For more complicated ode one should constrain all the symmetrie conditions. That's what I wnated to avoid.